# How to select same measure twice, but apply 2 different selects on this 2 measures?

Tags: mdx

Here is my mdx :

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Amount],[Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 FROM (select ({[Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20130119] : [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20130114]}) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [terst])
   WHERE ([Dim Client].[Common Client Name].&[Test]) 
 CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

this two measures have identical output, since both should only containt amount between two dates 20130119 and 20130114.

What shall i do if the second measure in the mdx should containt amount between  2 different dates for example (20140116 and 20140616) but still be in the same mdx request?

Comment: use union all in your query

Comment: How would that query look like? i cant really see how i can use union here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if I understand the request, you want to be able to display two date ranges for the same measure side by side, as single columns? If so you need two custom members that are aggregates of the date range requested, and then use them to select from the measure like so:

```
With Member [Date].[FirstPeriod] as
    aggregate(
        {[Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20130119]:[Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20130114]})

Member [Date].[SecondPeriod] as
    aggregate(
        {[Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20140119]:[Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20140114]})

select {([Measures].[Amount],[Date].[FirstPeriod]), ([Measures].[Amount],[Date].[SecondPeriod])} on 0
from [terst]
where ([Dim Client].[Common Client Name].&[Test])
```

Hope that's what you needed :)